# Estimating hazard ratios for values of a continuous predictor without catagorizing

Tags: survival, cox-model, measurement-error, time-varying-covariate

I have a dataset where I am looking at time to diagnosis as a continuous predictor of mortality. Using a Cox model, I want to estimate HRs for values of this continuous predictor to be able to say that a delay in dx of x days confers x risk. I could categorize my time to dx variable but this will mean I lose information, and because this variable was derived and has non-differential measurement error, the reclassification will introduce differential misclassification.

If I assume a log linear relation between time to dx and mortality, what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a univariate Cox regression model with time to diagnosis as your sole predictor variable. By exponentiating the coefficient from this model, you get a hazard ratio that would be interpreted as a change in the risk of mortality for every unit change in time to diagnosis.

i.e. for an HR=1.50 "For every day increase in time to diagnosis the risk of 1-year mortality was 1.5 times greater".

Depending on what statistical software you're using, there are several ways to create this model. If you're using R you can use the coxph() function from the Survival package.

Comment: It would be the `coxph()` function, not the `survfit()`, otherwise excellent reply

Comment: @Denzo Good catch, thanks! I'll edit

Comment: Modeling the continuous predictor flexibly is even better. If you just use the continuous predictor as is, you make the assumption that the log hazard of the event is linearly related to the value of the variable. A regression spline can allow for a more complicated association, with the data telling you its form. See Chapter 2 of [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) for the principles, and Chapter 21 for application to survival models.

Comment: @EdM Brilliant! I've opted to use a cubic spline and am now thinking about the derivation of these HRs and the interpretations. Would I follow the same procedure I would have had I not used a spline to assess a more than one unit increase? For example, if I want to look at the HR of a 7 day delay in dx, I would multiply the regression coef and CI by 7 before exponentiating. I can then repeat this procedure for the intervals of interest (ex. delays of 14, 21, 28, 48 days).

Comment: @user405452 the coefficients for a spline need to be pugged back into the formula describing the spline to get the HR at any given value of a continuous predictor. That's not something I'd recommend that you try on your own. Use statistical software and show plots. Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) can do that; see Chapter 21 of his [online text](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/coxcase) for an example in a Cox model. Or use the`pspline()`function of the [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf).